# Strange wrinkles in my cloth sim

Tags: modifiers, cloth-simulation

[image: Strange cringles]

This is a problem with a bag I simulated. As you can tell there's these weird wrinkles near the bag's seam. My self-diagnosis is that there is a disparity between the large number of polygons near the bag's edge and on the bag's main body, and when I enable self-collision, they bunch together. The problem seems to get worse with each subdivision I add.

My cloth sim's parameters are all default except for pressure and its related attributes:

- Pressure = 81.7
- Pressure scale = 22
- Fluid Density = 100
- Self-collisions = on
- Distance = .001m
- Quality = 2

Comment: Subdividing might be the problem. Are you re-baking the cache for each subdivide?

Comment: I'm not even baking the results. Just tweaking it in real time as I go.

Comment: You probably should bake the simulation.